# How do I get passed " × MSBuild tools not found for version 17.0 (from environment)" error in VSCode and React Native?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I'm getting this error "‼ No public VS release found
i Trying pre-release VS
× Could not find MSBuild with VCTools for Visual Studio 17.0 or later. Make sure all required components have been installed
× It is possible your installation is missing required software dependencies. Dependencies can be automatically installed by running projectname\node_modules\react-native-windows\scripts\rnw-dependencies.ps1 from an elevated PowerShell prompt.
For more information, go to http://aka.ms/rnw-deps
Command failed. Re-run the command with --logging for more information."

when trying to run `npx react-native run-windows` in vscode.

I tried installing Visual Studio Community 2022 but had the same problem. In fact, when I try running in the powershell as an administrator `Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Scope Process -Force; iex (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://aka.ms/rnw-vs2022-deps.ps1');` I get "Checking Visual Studio 2022 (>= 17.9) & req. components         Failed". Help me out here. How can I fix this?